# Set priority between vertical and horizontal QToolBar positioning

Tags: qt, qt-creator, toolbar, qmainwindow, qtoolbar

I've searched for quite a long time, but I haven't managed to find a solution to this problem:
In QtCreator, I have a main window with 2 QToolBars, one vertical (Qt::LeftToolBarArea) and one horizontal (Qt::BottomToolBarArea). 
The idea is to have a main toolbar on the left and a secondary toolbar on the bottom, with just a few widgets.

Now the problem is that no matter what I try, when adding the bottom toolbar, the left one shrinks in height to make space for it.
Is it possible to invert the behaviour? **Have the bottom toolbar shrinked to make space for the vertical one?**

Qt documentation doesn't seem to deny this possibility:
[QMainWindow generic layout with no specification about horizontal toolbars being more "important" than others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKBVA.png)

Looking around I found this guy with the same problem (no luck, though):
https://forum.qt.io/topic/62936/qtoolbar-positioning-within-qmainwindow

And this other picture, but I'm not sure it's official:
[Possible priority (undocumented) between toolbars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ur1t.gif)

Does somebody knows if this is a lost cause or there's some trick to achieve what I'm looking for?

EDIT:

I've found exactly the thing I'm looking for, unfortunately it seems to be available only for QDockWidgets:
http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#setCorner

Answer (score 0):

Since Qt4, toolbars occupy their own areas around the central widget with fixed positions, so I don't believe there's a simple solution do to what you want by using the `QToolBar` directly. However, there is a simple solution with `QDockWidgets` (as you've pointed out). Simply put each `QToolBar` inside a separate `QDockWidget` and use `QMainWindow::setCorner(Qt::BottomLeftCorner, Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea)`

I currently don't have access to a compiler but should be something like:

```
QMainWindow mainWindow;
mainWindow.setCorner(Qt::BottomLeftCorner, Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea);

auto dock = new QDockWidget("Dock", &mainWindow);
auto windowInsideDock = new QMainWindow(dock, Qt::Widget);
auto toolBar = new QToolBar(windowInsideDock);
windowInsideDock->addToolBar(toolBar);
dock->setWidget(insideDock);
mainWindow.addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dock);
//... similar for bottom widget...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately in this application dockwidgets are already used. Furthermore, it seems impossibile to replicate a `QToolBar` behavior (unmovable, unresizable etc..) on a `QDockWidget`, especially when other `QDockWidgets` can move around and interact with the widget that you proposed.